# UIScrollView programmatically Scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I have a UITextView inside a UIScrollView that needs to automatically scroll once the user starts editing it. This is because the keyboard will cover the textview.

Here is the code -

In `viewDidLoad:`

```
feedBackformView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, segmentedControl.frame.origin.x + self.segmentedControl.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
feedBackformView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
feedBackformView.scrollEnabled = YES;
feedBackformView.delegate = self;
feedBackformView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
feedBackformView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
feedBackformView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 700);

commentsView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, emailField.frame.origin.y + 40, 250, 150)];
commentsView.delegate = self;
commentsView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
commentsView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
```

and here's the delegate method implementation -

```
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
    CGPoint point = textView.frame.origin;
    [scrollView setContentOffset:point animated:YES];
}
```

However, nothing happens.

Comment: what happens when you try to scroll with scrollRectToVisible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your are doing fine but use **feedBackformView** instead of  **scrollView**,while setting content offset in    `textViewDidBeginEditing:`method, just have a look on below code

```
feedBackformView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 200)];
feedBackformView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
feedBackformView.scrollEnabled = YES;
feedBackformView.delegate = self;
feedBackformView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
feedBackformView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
feedBackformView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 700);

commentsView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 40, 250, 150)];
commentsView.delegate = self;
commentsView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
commentsView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;

[feedBackformView addSubview:commentsView];
[self.view addSubview:feedBackformView];
```

in textview DelegateMethod,

```
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
  CGPoint point = textView.frame.origin;
  [feedBackformView setContentOffset:point animated:YES];
 }
```

hope it will hepls you...

Answer (score 1):

You can use scrollView `scrollRectToVisible:animated` or the `setContentOffset:animated` methods described here:
[UIScrollView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922-CH3-SW26)

Keep in mind that UITextView comes with its own scroll view. so you may not need to nest it inside another scrollview. But you may need to if your app is that interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Is your point of scrolling already at a visible point?

```
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
    // try this instead
    CGPoint point = CGPointMake(textView.frame.origin.x, 
                                textView.frame.origin.y + textView.frame.size.height);
    [scrollView setContentOffset:point animated:YES];

    // What does this produce?
    NSLog(@"%@ %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(scrollView.contentOffset),
                    NSStringFromCGRect(textView.frame));
}
```